Actions lose their slots when I export to .glb
Some context: I have a file with an armature from mixamo and several of their animations that I'm using as an animation library in Godot and another file, with the same armature which is the visual part of the character. Except I realized they were different, and the animation library armature had a different rest position. To fix this I appended the armature from the character file and since all bones have the same names, I can play the same actions. This kinda worked, in the sense that I can actually play the actions on the new armature, but for some reason whenever I export to .glb the actions lose their slots. At this point when I import the animations in Godot, some work, and some don't, but if I export the file again without the slots, no animations work. I'm confident this is an issue with how I'm exporting the file because when I import the .glb file in blender the animations are also broken.
The blend file in question:

